# Combine multiple database tables into one view

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

How can I display the data from two different database tables in one view? What I want to do is put "CreateBy" data from `Table2` into "CreateBy" data in `Table1`.

Both of these are from the same database but they are in different tables.

Here's a picture of `Table1`, that I want to modify (Column:Create By):

[image: Picture of Table1]

Here's a picture of `Table2`, that I want to take data from (Column:CreateBy):

[image: Picture of Table2]

Below is the code I'm current using:

```html
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[GetJobsReportListing]
 @Page int,
 @PageSize int,
 @TotalRecords int Output,
 @Webmaster varchar(50) = null,
 @consultantGUID varchar(50)= null,
 @CreateByGUID varchar(50)= null,
 @branchGUID varchar(50)= null,
 @OrderStatusGUID varchar(50) = null,
 @strYear varchar(10) = null,
 @strMonth varchar(10) =null
 
AS 
 
BEGIN
 BEGIN TRY
 begin transaction
 
 Declare @IsAdmin bit

 set @IsAdmin = (Select Top 1 IsAdmin From TBL_ConsultantUser Where ConsultantUserGUID=@Webmaster)

  if (@IsAdmin = '1')
   Begin
    set @Webmaster = null
   End
  Else
   Begin
   Declare @ConsultantRole varchar(50)

   set @ConsultantRole = (Select Top 1 ConsultantRoleGUID From TBL_ConsultantUser Where ConsultantUserGUID=@Webmaster)

   if (@ConsultantRole = '9199227d-1d40-4e7e-b532-cb4f3b3d9982')
    Begin
     set @branchGUID = (Select Top 1 BranchGUID From TBL_ConsultantUser Where ConsultantUserGUID=@Webmaster)
     set @Webmaster = null
    End
  End
  
  Declare @TBLReport as Table (
         [JobNo][varchar](50),
         [CompanyName][varchar](350),
         [JobPositionName][varchar](250),
         [SalaryRange][varchar](100),
         [JobBillRate][float],
         [JobCoordinatorGUID][varchar](50),
         [JobCoordinator][varchar](300),
         [BranchName][varchar](250),
         [CreateByGUID][varchar](50),
         [CreateByName][varchar](300),
         [OrderStatusName][varchar](100),
         [CreateDate][Datetime]
        )
  Insert Into @TBLReport
  (
   [JobNo],
   [CompanyName],
   [JobPositionName],
   [SalaryRange],
   [JobBillRate],
   [JobCoordinatorGUID],
   [JobCoordinator],
   [BranchName],
   [CreateByGUID],
   [CreateByName],
   [OrderStatusName],
   [CreateDate]
  ) 
  Select 
   TBL_JobPost.JobNo,
   TBL_Company.CompanyName,
   TBL_LK_JobPosition.JobPositionName,
   TBL_LK_Salary.SalaryRange,
   TBL_JobPost.JobBillRate,
   cuser_2.ConsultantUserGUID as 'JobCoordinatorGUID',
   cuser_2.ContactPerson as 'JobCoordinator',
   DDLBranch.BranchName,
   createby_1.CreateBy as 'CreateByGUID',
   cuser_1.ContactPerson,
   TBL_LK_OrderStatus.OrderStatusName,
   TBL_JobPost.CreateDate
  From
   TBL_JobPost
   Left Join TBL_Company
   On TBL_JobPost.CompanyGUID = TBL_Company.CompanyGUID
   Left Join TBL_LK_JobPosition
   On TBL_JobPost.JobPositionGUID = TBL_LK_JobPosition.JobPositionGUID
   Left Join TBL_LK_Salary
   On TBL_JobPost.SalaryGUID = TBL_LK_Salary.SalaryGUID
   Left Join TBL_LK_OrderStatus
   On TBL_JobPost.JobOrderStatusGUID = TBL_LK_OrderStatus.OrderStatusGUID
   Left Join TBL_ConsultantUser as cuser_1
   On TBL_JobPost.CreateBy = cuser_1.ConsultantUserGUID
   Left Join TBL_JobPostReply as createby_1
   On TBL_JobPost.CreateBy = createby_1.CreateBy
   Left Join TBL_ConsultantUser as cuser_2
   On TBL_JobPost.JobCoordinator = cuser_2.ConsultantUserGUID
   Left Join DDLBranch
   On cuser_2.BranchGUID = DDLBranch.BranchGUID
   Left Join TBL_JobPostReply
   On TBL_JobPost.JobPostGUID = TBL_JobPostReply.JobPostGUID
   Left Join TBL_LK_JobApplicationStatus
   On TBL_JobPostReply.StatusApplicationGUID = TBL_LK_JobApplicationStatus.JobApplicationStatusGUID
  Where
   (
   ISNULL(createby_1.CreateBy,'') = ISNULL(@Webmaster,ISNULL(createby_1.CreateBy,'')) 
   Or
   ISNULL(cuser_2.ConsultantUserGUID,'') = ISNULL(@Webmaster,ISNULL(cuser_2.ConsultantUserGUID,'')) 
   )
   And
   (
   ISNULL(cuser_1.BranchGUID,'') = ISNULL(@branchGUID,ISNULL(cuser_1.BranchGUID,''))
   Or
   ISNULL(cuser_2.BranchGUID,'') = ISNULL(@branchGUID,ISNULL(cuser_2.BranchGUID,''))
   )
   And
   ISNULL(TBL_JobPost.JobOrderStatusGUID,'') = ISNULL(@OrderStatusGUID,ISNULL(TBL_JobPost.JobOrderStatusGUID,''))
   And
   ISNULL(YEAR(Convert(varchar,TBL_JobPostReply.CreateDate,111)), '') = ISNULL(@strYear,ISNULL(YEAR(Convert(varchar,TBL_JobPostReply.CreateDate,111)), ''))
   AND 
   ISNULL(Month(Convert(varchar,TBL_JobPostReply.CreateDate,111)), '') = ISNULL(@strMonth,ISNULL(Month(Convert(varchar,TBL_JobPostReply.CreateDate,111)), ''))
  Group By
   TBL_JobPost.JobNo,
   TBL_Company.CompanyName,
   TBL_LK_JobPosition.JobPositionName,
   TBL_LK_Salary.SalaryRange,
   TBL_JobPost.JobBillRate,
   cuser_2.ConsultantUserGUID,
   cuser_2.ContactPerson,
   DDLBranch.BranchName,
   createby_1.CreateBy,
   cuser_1.ContactPerson,
   TBL_LK_OrderStatus.OrderStatusName,
   TBL_JobPost.CreateDate
 
 --Get Total Records-- (Editable Code)
 Set @TotalRecords = (SELECT 
       Count(*)as TotalRecords
       From 
       @TBLReport as vw1
       Where
       ISNULL(vw1.JobCoordinatorGUID,'') = ISNULL(@consultantGUID,ISNULL(vw1.JobCoordinatorGUID,''))
       AND
       ISNULL(vw1.CreateByGUID,'') = ISNULL(@CreateByGUID,ISNULL(vw1.CreateByGUID,''))
      );
 
 
 --Paging Calculations-- (Fixed Code)
    Declare @EndAtRecord int;
    Set @EndAtRecord = (@Page) * (@PageSize);
    
    If(@PageSize <> '0')
      Begin
       If(@TotalRecords <> '0')
        Begin
         If((@PageSize*@Page) > @TotalRecords)
         Begin
          Set @PageSize = @TotalRecords % @PageSize
         End
        End 
      End
    Else
     Begin
      Set @PageSize = @TotalRecords
      Set @EndAtRecord = @TotalRecords;
     End
 
 
 --Select Statement-- 
 SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT TOP (@PageSize) * FROM (
   --Main SQL-- (Editable Code))
   SELECT TOP (@EndAtRecord) 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY vw1.JobNo ASC) AS RowNumber,
    [JobNo],
    [CompanyName],
    [JobPositionName],
    [SalaryRange],
    [JobBillRate],
    [JobCoordinatorGUID],
    [JobCoordinator],
    [BranchName],
    [CreateByGUID],
    [CreateByName],
    [OrderStatusName],
    [CreateDate]
   From 
    @TBLReport as vw1
   Where
    ISNULL(vw1.JobCoordinatorGUID,'') = ISNULL(@consultantGUID,ISNULL(vw1.JobCoordinatorGUID,''))
    AND
    ISNULL(vw1.CreateByGUID,'') = ISNULL(@CreateByGUID,ISNULL(vw1.CreateByGUID,''))
   )as newtbl1
  ORDER by RowNumber DESC) as newtbl2
 ORDER by RowNumber ASC
 
 
 commit transaction    
 return 1
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
 rollback transaction
 EXEC InsertDatabaseErrorLog
 return 0
END CATCH

END
```

Comment: How about a [MCVE] instead of this wall of code?

Comment: Please include details of the two tables and how you would like them displayed (your current code is too long to quickly understand what it is doing). Two obvious options: joins (each table contributes to each display row) or union (each table provides different display rows).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for replying my question. I have edit my question above. @Steve